# How long should I stay outside Morocco before I can reenter?

Tags: filipino-citizens, morocco, repeat-visits

I am a Philippines passport holder and I am allowed 90-day visa free stay in Morocco. I arrived in Morocco on June 26 and will leave September 22 (88 days stay). I will travel to South America for 4 months and I plan to return to Morocco on January 25. Will my 90-day visa free stay be valid by that time?

OR to make the question more generic, how long should I stay outside Morocco for the 90-day visa free stay be reset/be valid again?

Answer (score 3):

A few days is more than enough. Actually leaving and re-entering the country at the same day would theoretically also work. You only need to get the stamp leaving the country and a new one with a new date entering the country.

The 4 months you will be staying outside of Morocco is absolutely sufficient to renew your right to a new 90 day free period..